# On fresh 16.04 install, booting went slow

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, performance

I installed a FRESH Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Wild Dog Pro from System 76.  Prior to the fresh install the system was booting perfectly.

I have updated all of the System 76 drivers per their instructions, and sadly, still slow on boot.  It seems to slow down right before the login screen is rendered.

I am using the NVIDIA 375 driver for my graphics card.

Output of "**systemd-analyze blame**":

```
      9.312s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.799s systemd-udev-settle.service
       731ms snapd.service
       401ms dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
       309ms vboxdrv.service
       260ms snapd.autoimport.service
       226ms lvm2-activation-net.service
       214ms lvm2-activation-early.service
       202ms lvm2-monitor.service
       179ms lvm2-activation.service
        62ms NetworkManager.service
        60ms udisks2.service
        56ms ModemManager.service
        54ms networking.service
        52ms accounts-daemon.service
        51ms apparmor.service
        46ms grub-common.service
        45ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        41ms snap-core-3017.mount
        40ms console-setup.service
        38ms snap-discord-23.mount
        38ms lightdm.service
        37ms thermald.service
        34ms gpu-manager.service
        32ms systemd-journald.service
        32ms keyboard-setup.service
        32ms upower.service
        30ms snap-core-3291.mount
        29ms snap-core-3247.mount
        27ms irqbalance.service
        26ms apport.service
        25ms systemd-logind.service
        24ms plymouth-start.service
        21ms systemd-udevd.service
        20ms ondemand.service
        17ms systemd-modules-load.service
        17ms speech-dispatcher.service
        16ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        15ms pppd-dns.service
        12ms polkitd.service
        12ms avahi-daemon.service
        12ms dev-loop0.device
        11ms colord.service
        11ms plymouth-read-write.service
        11ms user@108.service
        11ms user@1000.service
        10ms rsyslog.service
        10ms systemd-update-utmp.service
         9ms alsa-restore.service
         9ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d770f4b9\x2d19ae\x2d4121\x2dab29\x2d0c469c63eec3.service
         9ms dev-mqueue.mount
         8ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
         7ms wpa_supplicant.service
         6ms systemd-timesyncd.service
         6ms bluetooth.service
         5ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
         5ms ufw.service
         5ms dev-loop1.device
         5ms kmod-static-nodes.service
         4ms dev-loop2.device
         4ms systemd-sysctl.service
         4ms systemd-journal-flush.service
         4ms dev-loop3.device
         4ms dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap
         4ms boot.mount
         3ms systemd-random-seed.service
         3ms resolvconf.service
         3ms systemd-remount-fs.service
         3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms dns-clean.service
         3ms dev-hugepages.mount
         3ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
         3ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         2ms vboxweb-service.service
         2ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms ureadahead-stop.service
         1ms setvtrgb.service
         1ms systemd-rfkill.service
         1ms vboxautostart-service.service
         1ms nvidia-persistenced.service
         1ms snapd.socket
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms rc-local.service
       786us plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

Comment: can you add the output of `sudo systemd-analyze blame`?

Comment: Sure thing, here it is:  Startup finished in 6.723s (kernel) + 14.592s (userspace) = 21.316s

Comment: that's a pretty quick boot.

Comment: With the same machine, before the clean install, it was almost half that.  Something odd is happening moments before the Ubuntu splash screen and login.

Comment: Included the complete "blame" tag data dump in the opening post.